# What is meant by ‘define model class’ in pytorch documentation?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

On the pytorch documentation page about saving and loading models, it says that when loading a saved model, `# Model class must be defined somewhere` [https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#:~:text=%23%20Model%20class%20must%20be%20defined%20somewhere](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#:%7E:text=%23%20Model%20class%20must%20be%20defined%20somewhere)

Maybe my question is silly, but what does class in this context refer to? Thanks in advance.

Earlier on the page, the 'loading-of-a-model process' is described such as

```
Load:

model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

Comment: It refers to the structure of the model, as you may know, any `Pytorch` model should implement some methods, like `forward()`, using this method the data flow of the model is determined. Therefore whenever you want to load serialized model weights you need to define the model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class in that context refers to the class of the model you’re trying to load with `torch.load`. The class must be defined because that function will construct the model object using the model class name stored in `PATH`. Thus, the construction will fail if the class with that name is not defined somewhere before `torch.load` is executed. This process is similar to how [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) loads a .pkl file (in fact I think `torch.load` uses pickle by default).

Note that the model class definition is not needed if you save and load the model’s state dict (the recommended way) because state dicts are Python dicts with strings as keys and `torch.Tensor` as values. Dicts and strings are built-ins so they’re always defined, and `torch.Tensor` is always defined whenever you import `torch` to use `torch.load`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the model class as, for example, explained [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/introyt/modelsyt_tutorial.html). Re-using the example from the linked website as a random example, a class for `TheModelClass` could be defined as follows:

```
class TheModelClass(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(TheModelClass, self).__init__()

        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(100, 200)
        self.activation = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(200, 10)
        self.softmax = torch.nn.Softmax()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear1(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        x = self.linear2(x)
        x = self.softmax(x)
        return x
```